# Does "somehow" mean "for some reason" here?

Tags: word-meaning

She suddenly smiled, somehow amused by this.

Does "somehow" here mean "for some reason"?

Comment: Yes, it implies that there was a reason which was not obvious to others.

Answer (score 2):

[Somehow](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/somehow) means "in some way; by some means" or "for a reason that is not known or specified."

So, yes, somehow means for some (unspecified) reason.